# Server busy, closing transmission channel. Try again later while sending mail in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I want to send mail. I have following code which was working perfectly. But since few days, I am getting following error.

> **Error: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Server busy, closing transmission channel. Try
>   again later**

Code:

```
try
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("xxx@gmail.com", "yyy@gmail.com"))
    {
        mm.Subject = "Registration Successfully";
        mm.Body = "You are registered successfully. Welcome.";
        mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "password");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

I have read following blogs and tried but didnt work.

1- [Email alerts -while sending mail to multiple user 1 by 1 getting error as server busy](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/738398/Email-alerts-while-sending-mail-to-multiple-user-b)

2- [Send Bulk Email From Yahoo and Hotmail Using ASP.Net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/send-bulk-email-from-yahoo-and-hotmail-using-Asp-Net/)

Answer (score 0):

don't use SMTP `smtp.gmail.com` some times create problem

best solution

```
        mm.Subject = "Registration Successfully";
        mm.Body = "You are registered successfully. Welcome.";
        mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "domainname.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("demo@domainname.com", "password");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
```

Comment: If this is my email address `test@gmail.com`, what should be the `smtp.Host = ?`

Comment: your domain provide mail address?

Comment: create mail address in your hosting panel

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting what do you mean. By the way I think `smtp.gmail.com` is host for all Gmail account. Plz correct me. Can you plz edit your answer with this email address? Sender = `test@gmail.com` & Receiver = 'test@yahoo.com'.

Comment: you dont use gmail mail id i suggest you use domain mail id

Comment: why you want use gmail mail id?

Comment: It can be anything. It is just an example. It can be Gmail, Yahoo, Exchange or anything else. The point is it stopped to work suddenly. Do I need to take care anything else rather host?